# xslt for each not working

Tags: xml, xslt

xml

```
<MessageBody>
    <SerialNumbers>
        <cmn:Serial>010088202501033821100011946933</cmn:Serial>
        <cmn:Serial>010088202501033821100015310495</cmn:Serial>
        <cmn:Serial>010088202501033821100018139350</cmn:Serial>
        <cmn:Serial>010088202501033821100012121992</cmn:Serial>
        <cmn:Serial>010088202501033821100016483276</cmn:Serial>
        <cmn:Serial>010088202501033821100012414042</cmn:Serial>
        <cmn:Serial>010088202501033821100011320392</cmn:Serial>
        <cmn:Serial>010088202501033821100016102891</cmn:Serial>
        <cmn:Serial>010088202501033821100013578725</cmn:Serial>
        <cmn:Serial>010088202501033821100018119185</cmn:Serial>
    </SerialNumbers>

</MessageBody>
```

xslt

```
    <xsl:for-each select="cmn:Serial">
    <fieldvalidation>
                <validtedfield>Serial</validtedfield>
                <value><xsl:value-of select="SerialNumbers/cmn:Serial"/></value>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="SerialNumbers/cmn:Serial != ''">    
                <status>Valid</status>
                <reason></reason>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise> 
                <status>Not Valid</status>
                <reason>Serial should not be empty.</reason>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </fieldvalidation>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I tried to convert transform but i struggle at   I did't get any errors transformation working fine for other xml tags but the serials not shown at output xml

Comment: Your source XML doesn't contain the declaration of the namespace so it isn't valid. Can you update the XML so it is complete and valid? Also, your XSLT doesn't have the namespace either - without seeing the complete XML/XSLT it's hard to know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi finally i have got correct answer

```
    <xsl:for-each select="//cmn:Serial">
    <fieldvalidation>
                <validtedfield>Serial</validtedfield>
                <value><xsl:value-of select="."/></value>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=".!= ''">    
                <status>Valid</status>
                <reason></reason>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise> 
                <status>Not Valid</status>
                <reason>Serial should not be empty.</reason>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </fieldvalidation>
</xsl:for-each>
```

inside the loop you have to set  like this to get the all the feild values. if you set  like this you will get the value for all field which is equal to first field's value

Answer (score 1):

If the `for-each` processes the `cmn:Serial` elements then the paths inside need to be relative so to select each element inside instead of `<value><xsl:value-of select="SerialNumbers/cmn:Serial"/></value>` you simply need `<value><xsl:value-of select="."/></value>` and instead of `test="SerialNumbers/cmn:Serial != ''"` you simply need `test=". != ''"`.

Comment: Then edit your question and show minimal but complete code samples with all namespaces, otherwise, as Matt Jones said in a comment, it is not possible to tell what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The for-each select expression needs either a fully qualified expression to the node list you need to select or a wildcard option to select all at any level of depth as below.
This should work for you:

```
xsl:for-each select="//cmn:Serial"
```

Comment: Hi, xsl:for-each select="//cmn:Serial" it's working means it's goes inside the loop and get serial number field which are equal to number of field inside the loop but the problem is all the serial fields are getting value from first serial eliment

Comment: Inside the loop, use a relative select expression like select=“.”